# SQL databases id change

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL databases.
I have Question Groups (parent ID) and Questions and Answers (Child ID) in it.

Example:
Banking (Question group) ID=10
have 50 questions and answers in this question group with child id= 1,2,3 so on
for each question and answer.

I want to change Question group ID from 10 to 1 ( ID 1 has no any question group).
when I change ID 10 to 1, it changes but questions and answers in this question group remains with previous parent id i.e. 10.

I wanted to change Question ad Answers also move to ID 1 from 10.

any solution. I have attached screenshots[image: mySQL]
[image]

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `questions_table` SET `id`=1         WHERE `id`=10;
UPDATE `answers_table`   SET `parent_id`=10 WHERE `parent_id`=1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hossam Sir

Comment: Hosam Sir... Need a little help in mySQL.